# Help developing grid maps

Tags: tiles, tilemap

I have been working with Tiled and Cocos2d lately but am having problems understanding how Im suppose to be doing the maps.
Tiled is not an image editor, so I create my tileset in Gimp.  However it seems impossible for me to get grid lines that are the same as Tiled and so I dont know prior to importing the image (into Tiled) where the grid lines will be.

See the image below.  Both Tiled and Gimp's grid lines are set to 32px however the grid lines are nothing alike between the two programs

How can I get the grid lines to match so that I can draw stuff knowing how many tiles it will take.  Is there a better program for creating tileset or another way to do it?

[image]

Comment: Are those green tiles are different tiles?

Comment: this is my first map, and just trying to get a feel for how to do it.  I understand this map is lacking, but why would I go all out at this stage prior to understanding all this stuff.  Besides the green tiles, what makes this "horrible" what is a better way?

Comment: Seems to me you are duplicating a lot of tiles that you shouldn't need to.  Consider creating tileable textures instead.  You will eliminate the hundreds of green tiles down to just a few.  For example, instead of trying to fit your grid on top of your picture, create a multiple pictures based on your grid size.  If you have 32x32 tiles, create your images based on that size.

Comment: Right and thats the same if I scale these objects to 32x32.  But the problem remains.  I need these grid lines to match up in order to properly place them on my tileset image.  Otherwise I would be moving them in gimp, saving, then opening it in tileset just to see the placement of the items to the grid lines.  There should be a way to get the gridlines to match up in Gimp so I can plot the items first, then export to tiled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the grid lines in Tiled are 64px, not 32. If you look at the top-left 'thing', it occupies 128px according to Gimp (and therefore takes up 4 grid spaces across, as expected). However, in Tiled it only uses up 2 grid spaces across. This leads me to believe that actually, the Tiled map editor uses a 64px by 64px grid, not a 32x32 one.